# Utilizar date picker em asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datetime, datapicker

Estou a criar um site em asp.net (vb) com uma master page por trás e não consigo por o date picker a funcionar
Conseguem me ajudar ou indicar um data picker mesmo dos nuggets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizei o date picker deste [site](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>


</body>
</html>
```